# Ruby class which could take an array of rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in the process of learning Ruby/Rails. I'm currently learning to create a model/classes.

I have an existing class that has these methods

```
  def duration
    (start_on..end_on).count
  end

  def items
    space.available_items
  end

  def available_items
    duration >= 365 ? items.not_including_insurance : items
  end
```

In the class above, I have a method called `available_items` that checks if the duration is more than 365 days, then item will not be included in the array.

Rather than coupling the duration logic to the existing class, I think it's better to encapsulate it in another class which could take an array of rules to apply to the items.

So instead, in the above class, in the `available_items` method I can do something like:

`policy.apply(items)`

which will return all of the items which satisfy the rules.
And in the future, I can append more rules and keeps it flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `include`ing you module you still can define `available_items` method with custom rules (and have a generic one upstream), this is the easy way.

As for "passing" parameters to a strategy - it can be accomplished in a Concern like:

```rb
module SomePolicy
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def my_policiable(param)
      has_many :prices, class_name: 'Pricing::SimplePrice', as: :priceable
      # ...
      define_method(:available_items) {
        if param == :foo
          # ...
        end
      }
    end
  end
end
```

```
include SomePolicy

my_policiable(:foo)
```

trick is that the method is run in class context, there based on params you can define methods differently (but note that in example above `if param..` will run for each resulting method invocation)